# Moshi equivalent to Gson.toJson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, moshi

I'm new to Moshi and I was thinking to implement it to replace my Gson lib.
Can't figure out how exactly I can convert a model class into a string in JSON format.

My model is UiGeneralCategory

I have this example but I think I'm a little overburned because something doesn't line up.

[image]

ok,

val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(UiGeneralCategory::class.java)

works, now i have to replace all the ArrayLists in models and test it

Comment: Btw, you can cache the JsonAdapter, so you don't have to do the lookup in every iteration.

Comment: @Vlad.mir, do you want to post your solution as separate answer? That way this question is marked as answered and it might be easier for others to find the solution. Though it surprises me a bit that your original code did not work, because that appears to be the same as shown in the Moshi README examples (unless I am overlooking something here).

Comment: @EricCochran I'll try it, for now, have just used it to map API to local model and replace toJson and fromJson but it doesn't seem to work faster than Gson as I was expecting

Comment: @Marcono1234 Sure, I was also a bit surprised by the documentation and this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is my class for toJson/fromJson conversion (with generic object),
It uses just one instance of the Moshi builder for optimization (from what I have seen is something like 400-500 millis)

```
import android.util.Log
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import java.lang.reflect.Type

class MoshiHelper {

private var mMoshiInstance: Moshi = getMoshi()

private fun getMoshi(): Moshi {
    Log.d("testMoshiInstance112", "initialized ")
    return Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
}

companion object {
    private var mInstance: MoshiHelper? = null

    fun getInstance(): MoshiHelper {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = MoshiHelper()
        }
        return mInstance!!
    }

}


fun <T> moshiFromJson(json: String, type: Type): T {
    //use jsonAdapter<T> for generic adapter
    val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<T> = mMoshiInstance.adapter(type)
    return jsonAdapter.fromJson(json)!!
}

fun <T> moshiToJson(obj: T, type: Type): String {
    //use jsonAdapter<T> for generic adapter
    val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<T> = mMoshiInstance.adapter(type)

    return jsonAdapter.toJson(obj)
}

}
```

And the usage:

```
var mMoshiHelper = MoshiHelper.getInstance()

var mPayload: String = mMoshiHelper.moshiToJson(mUiLocalModel, UiMyLocalModel::class.java)

var mUiLocalModel: UiMyLocalModel = mMoshiHelper.moshiFromJson(mPayload, UiMyLocalModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Your `getInstance()` function might not be thread-safe; might be better to use [`lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#lazy-properties) or change `mInstance` to `val` and initialize it eagerly, assuming that the overhead is pretty small.

Comment: Why not just use object instead of going this way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the extension function:

```kotlin
import com.squareup.moshi.adapter
```

This issue also came up [here](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1532). Apparently this is an IntelliJ bug because code completion (when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) correctly suggests the extension function. Only the error dialog you have shown does not suggest the extension function for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried the quick fix, with gradle implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:1.14.0" and the import but doesn't seem to solve the issue, I will see more when I get some free time. Cheers